# Setting multiple font colors within an Excel cell using R

Tags: r, excel

So I'm using openxlsx in R to create an excel file and I want to set some style parameters based on a sentimental analysis (using R's sentimentr library) of the text found within a certain column of cells. I've already created an array where each element is an array of the sentences in the text at that row index in the original file. I'd like to color positively scored sentences green, and negatively scored sentences red. However, it seems like openxlsx's `createStyle` function only works on an entire cell.

I've considered separating the positive and negative into separate columns and coloring them that way, but this is less than ideal as it is likely to screw up the order of the text. Is there a library out there that can help with this? Here's some pseudocode of what I'd like this program to do:

```py
getUserSelectedFile()
comments = GetExcelColumn("Comments")
split_comments = comments.SplitBySentences() # Same as comments, but each 
for each element in split_comments { # element is now separated by sentence.
    for each sentence in element {
        if sentiment score of sentence < 0 {
            find sentence in original comment in original excel file and color it red
        } else {
            find sentence in original comment in excel file and color it green
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should post the top of the file you get when you export a comma separated file. You should also not post pseudo code that uses non-existent functions in a particular library. It also appears you think R is Ptython  ... it's not the case that you can sent actions to objects with the dot-notation. Otherwise this is more like a request to "write my project for me" which is generally not well received by SO answerers. So for now I'm voting to close as too broad. I can always reverse my vote if you make this question more focused.

Comment: I'm aware that R and python are different. I didn't want to include my actual code because it wasn't originally mine, I'm just adding functionality for a coworker. I have the code and the know how to do all of what I need done except for having multiple font colors in a single cell. I don't see how asking if R is capable of doing something and to be pointed in somewhere that I could find out how to do said thing is asking SO to do a project for me... I don't even think the pseudocode is super necessary to answer the question. I only included is on the off chance someone requested it.

Comment: Asking to be "pointed somewhere" without any coding or testing is explicitly  list as a reason for question closure. It wasn't the reason I chose because I thought you needed the entire process coded. This is the text of the close vote reason: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: The problem is that I need to be able to set multiple font colors in a single cell with r.  I haven't been able to try anything to solve it because I don't know of any library with that functionality. Neither the openxlsx package or the xlsx package seem to have this capability